# How to remove dependency on Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core from EF Code First model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependencies, asp.net-identity, .net-assembly

I am using Identity Framework with my application and I have a class library `model.dll` that contains my Entity Framework model (actually only the POCO classes, not the `DbSet`s).

In that model, there's a `User` class that inherits from `IdentityUser` creating a dependency on `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll`.

There are multiple projects (among them a web client, and a window service) that consume this class library. The web client, which is a MVC 5 application, uses Identity Framework so this dependency is obviously OK. However, the Windows service also uses `model.dll` library, and ideally, it should not reference `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll` or `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll` since it does not use Identity Framework under the hood.

I've looked at creating custom Identity Managers and Stores, but they all imply that my `User` class **must** implement `IUser` or `IUser<T>` interface defined in  `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll`.

Is there a way to create Identity Managers/Stores without having this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

hi actually i dont thinkits possible in my previous app which was N-Tier with WebAPI i have to create a custom Identity managers but i had to inherit the IUser
  although i think you can get rid of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll but not sure

Comment: Removing .EntityFramework is possible by creating custom Managers and Stores. However, it seems that removing all Identity dependencies is impossible. This strikes me as a strange decision, since SimpleMembership (which is a predecessor to Identity) simply needed you to provide a custom User type and tell which properties to use for ID and Username, if I recall correctly.